# How to run Postgresql trigger from C# code [web/windows application]

Tags: npgsql

I want to get indication of Postgresql table changes in my c# code. is it possible and if it is, please mention ways to achieve it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and than asked your question

Comment: yes already read

Comment: Give more details about what you are trying to achieve.